# bash: /usr/bin/npx: No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, npm, ubuntu-18.04, npx

I try to create a new react project:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

I get an error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/npx: No such file or directory
```

Tried solution:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists
```

The version:

```
npm -v npx
6.14.14
```

What should I do?

---

```
which npx
/usr/local/bin/npx
```

.

```
ls -l /usr/bin | grep npx
(no result)
```

.

```
whereis npx
npx: /usr/local/bin/npx /usr/share/man/man1/npx.1
```

Comment: add output of `which npx`, `ls -l /usr/bin | grep npx`, `whereis npx` commands

Comment: Did you try to restart bash terminal window? This may be a reason. Also you may avoid this error by using full path: `/usr/local/bin/npx create-react-app my-app`.

Comment: maybe this topic can help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/250971/no-such-file-or-directory-error-while-using-npm

Comment: bash restart fixed it. I did not expect this from linux bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the solution was to restart the bash terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For me,  the solutions was: get it off  from gitIgnore the folder dist/ .

Comment: Hi, that would not solve the issue here. Since /usr/bin/npx is not part of the dist directory anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).